# How can I remove an item from a json array without using jQuery?

Tags: javascript

I have the following array:

```
$scope.myData = [
                 {id: 1, age: 50},
                 {id: 2, age: 43},
                 {id: 8, age: 27},
                 {id: 9, age: 29}
                ];
```

What I would like to do is to remove a row if given the row id value. I understand that I could use something like:

```
$scope.myData.splice(0,1);
```

But how can I determine the row number if for example I am given:

```
var idToRemove = 8;
```

Here is a solution I was given that uses jQuery. Unfortunately I don't use jQuery so I am looking for a javascript solution.

```
    function remove(array, property, value) {
        $.each(array, function(index, result) {
            if (result[property] == value) {
                array.splice(index, 1);
            }
        });    
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My version..

```
function remove(property, num, arr) {
    for (var i in arr) {
        if (arr[i][property] == num)
            arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
remove('id', 8, myData);
```

Comment: Why are you using a `for in` loop with an array?

Comment: @AlexCheuk Well, you shouldn't, unless you do it right. It will loop over the `length` and any other properties, including custom `prototype` ones.

Comment: @AlexCheuk: There are lots of things you "can" do in JavaScript. Doesn't mean they're good.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way that works, with looping backwards (in case the same property you're targeting matches more than once):

```
function remove(array, property, value) {
    var i, j, cur;
    for (i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        cur = array[i];
        if (cur[property] === value) {
            array.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/RbfTt/2/

And here's the same thing with a `while` loop:

```
function remove(array, property, value) {
    var i = array.length,
        j, cur;
    while (i--) {
        cur = array[i];
        if (cur[property] === value) {
            array.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/RbfTt/3/

Looping backwards is required when it's possible for more than one item to match, because `.splice()` will change the array in place and mess up the looping.

If multiple items shouldn't match, then a normal incrementing `for` loop will work, but you might want to put in a `break;` to make sure it doesn't continue looping.